# Прочитать файл docx в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, docx

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, мне нужно прочитать файл docx в Python, НО именно код файла, а не содержимый текст.

```
with open('MD_2.docx', encoding='cp1251', newline='') as file:
    print(file.readline())
```

Пытаюсь прочитать обычным методом, но не получается из-за ошибки

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 631: character maps to <undefined>
```

Как можно прочитать код файла ?

Comment: https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: `docx` — это на самом деле [`ZIP`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP)-архив, где текст хранится отдельным файлом в формате [`XML`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML). Для его получения рекомендуется воспользоваться сторонними библиотеками.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import codecs
filename = 'MD_2.docx'
with codecs.open(filename, encoding='utf-8',  errors='ignore') as f:
    print(f.readline())
```

Comment: **обратите внимание**, это правильное и рабочее решение именно для задачи топикстартера **"мне нужно прочитать файл docx в Python, НО именно код файла, а не содержимый текст"**, а не для чтения файлов формата docx: понятное дело, что для работы с MS Word есть библиотеки и вообще он как zip-файл представлен

Answer (score 2):

DOCX-файл это zip-архив. Распакуй его с помощью ZipFile, а затем прочитай файл "название документа/word/document.xml". В этом файле находится текст

Comment: [Как написать хороший ответ?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
from docxtpl import Document

source = Document("TEST.docx")    
paras = source.paragraphs
for para in paras:
    print(para.text)
```

Comment: См. первое предложение вопроса: "мне нужно прочитать файл docx в Python, **НО именно код файла, а не содержимый текст**."

Comment: Ну и использовать docxtpl (модуль для заполнения шаблонов docx) чтобы просто читать содержимое docx - это немного лишнее. Достаточно средств python-docx (который, кстати, ставится при установке docxtpl).

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]